# AssemblyInitialize in derived class

Tags: c#, mstest

I have a abstract base test class that has an `AssemblyInitialize` attribute applied to a method. But it will be never executed... The abstract base test class is in another assembly because it is for a generic extension. Any ideas how to solve this?

The code

```
[TestClass]
public abstract BaseTestClass
{    
   [AssemblyInitialize]
   public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
   {
      //DoDomething
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is happening because the Assembly is never initialized if you don't run tests from it. A solution I can give (maybe a fool one) is to use the `AssemblyInitialize` on the other assemblies and call the base `AssemblyInitialize`

In a `TestProject` which contains tests add the following code:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        // call the base AssemblyInitialize
        BaseTestProject.BaseTest.AssemblyInitialize(testContext);
    }

    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to implement a separate class without inheritance in your Test Project :

```
[TestClass]
public static class YourClass
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
    {
       //DoSomething
    }
}
```

It should be called.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I didn't mark the test base class with the `[TestClass]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to inject the `TextContext`, this is much cleaner and also allows to have `TestContext` available in a separate steps binding assembly if required easily.

```cs
class Hooks
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

    public Hooks(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, TestContext context)
    {
        _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    [AfterStep]
    public void AfterStep()
    {
    }
}
```